# Render and Preview are very different

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Attached is an image of something I'm working on. I am not sure why the background of the rendered (left image) does not show up which in the preview render (right image), the background appears.

[image]

Comment: Hi! It will probably be easier to identify the problem if you post the .blend file you're working with.